# how do I retrieve a user_id in the v2 API?

Tags: box-api

I'm writing an app to add/remove collaborators to a particular folder.  I need to only add collaborators that have setup their box account.  I see that the v2 API allows me to specify "The ID of this user" (as opposed to their email address) - how can I get their ID?  The v1 API has the get_user_id function - I don't see anything similar in the v2 docs...

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't an equivalent of get_user_id in the V2 API, so you'll have to resort to using email addresses. It should be noted that sending in an email of an unregistered user kicks off the registration process for the email address.

Comment: The problem is that the registration process is the box.com process -- which means the user doesn't get linked with our corporate storage (the user must go through an internal site to agree to some legal terms before they get the additional storage).  I'm trying to avoid the confusion that ensues when they realize they only have 5G of storage.  :)  Do you know if there are any plans to add this to the V2 API?